# Correct movement of a rotating figure with the mouse

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

The following example, places a Timage in a form; it creates a drawing inside it and then through 2 mouse events (MouseDown and MouseMove) on the image, we move the drawing correctly on screen with the mouse;

Now, if we remove the comment { MyImage.RotationAngle := 120;} from the code and activate the rotation of the figure previously plus 90 degrees, the movement is incorrect. I don't see what the problem is. *[It is necessary to be able to rotate the figure in screen several times while we can move the result in screen through the mouse.]*

```
unit UMoveShape;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Objects, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.FMXUI.Async, FireDAC.Stan.Intf,
  FMX.DialogService.Async,System.UIConsts,System.Math.Vectors,  FireDAC.Comp.UI;

type
  TForm16 = class(TForm)
    MyImage: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyImageMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure MyImageMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    Xdiff,Ydiff: single;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form16: TForm16;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm16.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
 MyRect1, MyRect2: TRectF;
 Path: TPathData;
begin
  MyImage.Width := 500;
  MyImage.Height := 500;
  MyImage.Bitmap.SetSize(Round(MyImage.Width), Round(MyImage.Height));
  MyRect1 := TRectF.Create(98, 100, 200, 200);
  MyRect2 := TRectF.Create(70, 90, 225, 210);
  Path := TPathData.Create;
  Path.AddEllipse(MyRect1);
  Path.AddRectangle(MyRect2, 0, 0, AllCorners);
  MyImage.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  MyImage.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawPath(path, 200);
  MyImage.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;

{If we rotate the image more than 90 degrees for example, the movement of the
 image with the cursor is erratic using the mouseDown and MouseMove routines.
 On the other way, if we don't rotate the movement is perfect.}

 // MyImage.RotationAngle := 120;
end;

procedure TForm16.MyImageMouseDown (Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
begin
  if (ssleft in shift) then
  begin
    Xdiff := X;
    Ydiff := y;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm16.MyImageMouseMove (Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if (ssleft in shift) then
  begin
    MyImage.Position.X := MyImage.Position.X + X - Xdiff;
    MyImage.Position.y := MyImage.Position.Y + Y - YDiff;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your rotated Image isn't moving the way you want is the fact that X and Y values that OnMouseMove event is returning are relative to your image client which is now rotated. So for instance if you have an image with width of 100 pixels, rotate it for 180 degrees and then move your mouse cursor to the left side of the image the X value will be 100 and not 0 as if the image would have not been rotated.

So in order to move your rotated image correctly you need to work with transform your X,Y values accordingly to the image rotation using vector rotation from rotation point of your image.

**EDIT:** In order to avoid doing vector transformation of X and Y yourself you can leave Delphi to do it for you. You can do this by transform all positional values from local client positions to Screen position using ClientToScreen method and then finally transform the new calculated position back from Screen position to client position using ScreenToClient method.

Here is example of such code:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  StartDragPos: TPointF;
  Dragging: Boolean;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if (ssleft in shift) then
  begin
    StartDragPos := ClientToScreen(Point(Round(X),Round(Y)));
    Dragging := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
begin
  if Dragging then
  begin
    Image1.Position.Point := ScreenToClient(ClientToScreen(Image1.Position.Point + ClientToScreen(Point(Round(X),Round(Y))) - StartDragPos));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  Dragging := False;
end;
```

PS:Also while writing this example code I figured out you can actually do mathematical operations directly with Points instead of doing calculations for X and Y values separately. At least you can do this in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. I'm not sure for older Delphi versions.

Hence why my example is adding and subtracting the points themselves instead of individual X and Y values.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the problem. Finally I have created an alternative code based on a mask that works correctly with any rotation.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52800952/1708841

Comment: Hello, I have tested the code you have proposed and there is some problem when the figure is rotated. I accompany test in video. https://1drv.ms/v/s!AqdWVn6k-HLbgqRxNKdQ7Gc_CXHqbQ

Comment: I have tested the code again and I can confirm there is some problem. For the reasons unknown when image rotation is closing 60 degrees positive or negative rotation there appears to be some precision loss in calculation since the image starts jumping around violently. I'll try to debug this thing more thoroughly as I get more time.

Answer (score 1):

I share the code of a possible solution using a mask.

It is based on creating a transparent mask that covers the entire image. Mouse movement routines will be based on the events in the Timage mask, which always remains unrotated at 0 degrees, while the rotated image copies the mask position coordinates when moved. There are some small limitations that are described in the comments.

Test: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AqdWVn6k-HLbgqRw352kQ1HjuIJ5Hw

```
unit UMoveShape;

interface

uses System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, 
System.Variants, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, 
FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Objects, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.FMXUI.Async, FireDAC.Stan.Intf,
FMX.DialogService.Async, System.UIConsts, System.Math.Vectors, 
FireDAC.Comp.UI, FMX.Edit,FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo;

type
  TForm1 = class (TForm)
    MyImage: TImage;
    MyImageMask: TImage;
    EditDegrees: TEdit;
    ButtonRotate: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate (Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyImageMaskMouseMove (Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, 
     Y: Single);
    procedure MyImageMaskMouseDown (Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; 
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure ButtonRotateClick (Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    Xdiff, Ydiff: single;
    MyRect1, MyRect2: TRectF;
    Path: TPathData;

    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1 : TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.ButtonRotateClick (Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyImage.RotationAngle := EditDegrees.Text.ToSingle;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate (Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Original Image
  MyImage.Width   := 300;
  MyImage.Height  := 300;
  MyImage.Bitmap.SetSize (Round (MyImage.Width), Round (MyImage.Height));
  MyRect1      := TRectF.Create (98, 100, 200, 200);
  MyRect2      := TRectF.Create (70, 90, 225, 210);

  Path         := TPathData.Create;
  Path.AddEllipse (MyRect1);
  Path.AddRectangle (MyRect2, 0, 0, AllCorners);

  MyImage.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  MyImage.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawPath (path, 200);
  MyImage.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;

  MyImageMask.Width := MyImage.Width;
  MyImageMask.Height := MyImage.Height;
  MyImageMask.Position := MyImage.Position;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyImageMaskMouseDown (Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; 
 Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if (ssleft in shift) then
  begin
    Xdiff := X;
    Ydiff := y;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyImageMaskMouseMove (Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; 
 X, Y: Single);
begin
  if (ssleft in shift) then
  begin
    MyImageMask.Position.X := MyImage.Position.X + X - Xdiff;
    MyImageMask.Position.y := MyImage.Position.Y + Y - YDiff;
    MyImage.Position.X     := MyImageMask.Position.X;
    MyImage.Position.y     := MyImageMask.Position.Y;
    Form1.Caption          := 'X:' + MyImage.Position.X.ToString + ' Y: ' + 
     MyImage.Position.y.ToString;
  end;
end;
```

end.

Comment: There is one problem with your approach. If you try to grab your rotated image by a corner it won't work since the roner of your rotated image extend past the size of your ImageMask.

Comment: Yes, you are right at that particular point. I think that for this case we can slightly enlarge the proportion of the transparent mask, so that it always contains the image in any angle, in my tests everything works quite well. In any case, his proposal is more correct at the mathematical level, but I have not been able to create a code with vectors, which is probably not as complex as I suppose.

Comment: Alternatively, as an aid, by placing the cursor on the image and the cursor within the perimeter of the mask, we draw its outline with a faint line. In this way the user always uses the dimensioned space for movement.

Comment: Enlarging the mask to cover the entire rotated image can have another problem. If you have two rotated images close to each other their masks may be overlapping so while you attempt to drag one you might end up dragging another one because its mask is positioned above the mask of the image you are trying to drag. Any way I have edited my answer with a working code where I transform all positional values fro client positional value to Screen Position first do the math and then transform the new position back to client position.

Answer (score 0):

```
//First of all load a simple Bitmap in your MyImage.

unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

  type
  TRGB = packed record
    b: byte;
    g: byte;
    r: byte;
  end;
  PRGB = ^TRGB;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MyImage: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyImageMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure MyImageMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure Rotate( bmp:TBitmap; Angle: double;fillColor: TColor);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Xdiff,Ydiff: integer;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyImage.Width := 500;
  MyImage.Height := 500;

 Rotate ( MyImage.Picture.Bitmap, 120, form1.Color);



end;

procedure TForm1.MyImageMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
 if (ssleft in shift) then
  begin
    Xdiff := X;
    Ydiff := y;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyImageMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if (ssleft in shift) then
  begin
    MyImage.left := MyImage.left + X - Xdiff;
    MyImage.top := MyImage.top + Y - YDiff;
  end;
end;
procedure TForm1.Rotate( bmp:TBitmap; Angle: double; fillColor: TColor);
var
  dst: TBitmap;

  parx1, parx2: pinteger;
  a, tsin, tcos, cxSrc, cySrc, cxDest, cyDest: Double;
  fx, fy: Integer;
  dw, dh,  x, y: Integer;
  px: pbyte;
  arx1, arx2: pintegerarray;
  ary1, ary2: Integer;
  ps, pd: pbyte;
  dw1, dh1: Integer;
  prgb_s, prgb_d: PRGB;
  srcrows: ppointerarray;
  iangle: Integer;
  prog, lprog: Integer;
  aTRGB:trgb;

  procedure Rot90(inv: Boolean);
  var
    x, y: Integer;
    mulx, muly, addx, addy: Integer;
  begin
    dw := bmp.height; dw1 := dw-1;
    dh := bmp.Width;  dh1 := dh-1;
    dst:= TBitmap.Create;
    dst.Width := dw;
    dst.height := dw;
    dst.PixelFormat:=  pf24bit;
    dst.Canvas.Brush.Color := fillColor;
    dst.Canvas.FillRect(Rect (0,0,dw ,dh)  );

    if inv then
    begin
      mulx := -1;
      muly := 1;
      addx := dw1;
      addy := 0;
    end
    else
    begin
      mulx := 1;
      muly := -1;
      addx := 0;
      addy := dh1;
    end;
    for x := 0 to dw1 do
    begin
      ps := bmp.ScanLine[addx+x*mulx];
      prgb_s := PRGB(ps);
      for y := 0 to dh1 do
      begin
        prgb_d := dst.Scanline[addy+y*muly];
        inc(prgb_d, x);
        prgb_d^ := prgb_s^;
        inc(prgb_s);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  procedure Rot180;
  var
    x, y: Integer;
  begin
    dw := bmp.width; dw1 := dw-1;
    dh := bmp.height;  dh1 := dh-1;
    dst:= TBitmap.Create;
    dst.Width := dw;
    dst.height := dw;
    dst.PixelFormat:=  pf24bit;
    dst.Canvas.Brush.Color := fillColor;
    dst.Canvas.FillRect(Rect (0,0,dw ,dh)  );
    for y := 0 to dh1 do
    begin
      pd := dst.ScanLine[dh1 - y];
      ps := bmp.Scanline[y];
      prgb_d := PRGB(pd);
      prgb_s := PRGB(ps);
      inc(prgb_s, dw1);
      for x := 0 to dw1 do
      begin
        prgb_d^ := prgb_s^;
        inc(prgb_d);
        dec(prgb_s);
      end;
    end;
  end;



begin

  if (Frac(angle) = 0) and ((trunc(angle) mod 90) = 0) then
  begin
    iangle := trunc(angle) mod 360;
    case iangle of
      90 : Rot90(false);
      180 : Rot180;
      270 : Rot90(true);
      -90 : Rot90(true);
      -180 : Rot180;
      -270 : Rot90(false);
    end;
    bmp.Assign( dst );
    FreeAndNil(dst);
    exit;
  end;

  a := angle * pi / 180;
  dw := round(abs(bmp.width * cos(a)) + abs(bmp.height * sin(a)));
  dh := round(abs(bmp.width * sin(a)) + abs(bmp.height * cos(a)));
  dw1 := dw-1;
  dh1 := dh-1;

    dst:= TBitmap.Create;
    dst.Width := dw;
    dst.height := dw;
    dst.PixelFormat:=  pf24bit;
    dst.Canvas.Brush.Color := fillColor;
    dst.Canvas.FillRect(Rect (0,0,dw ,dh)  );

  tsin := sin(a);
  tcos := cos(a);
  cxSrc := (bmp.Width - 1) / 2;
  cySrc := (bmp.Height - 1) / 2;
  cxDest := (dst.Width - 1) / 2;
  cyDest := (dst.Height - 1) / 2;
  getmem(arx1, sizeof(integer) * dst.Width);
  getmem(arx2, sizeof(integer) * dst.Width);
  for x := 0 to dst.Width - 1 do
  begin
    arx1[x] := round( cxSrc + (x - cxDest) * tcos );
    arx2[x] := round( cySrc + (x - cxDest) * tsin );
  end;

  getmem(srcrows, bmp.height*sizeof(pointer));
  for y := 0 to bmp.height-1 do
    srcrows[y] :=  bmp.ScanLine[y];

  for y := 0 to dh1 do
  begin
    px := dst.Scanline[y];
    ary1 := round( (y - cyDest) * tsin );
    ary2 := round( (y - cyDest) * tcos );

    parx1 := @arx1[0];
    parx2 := @arx2[0];

    prgb_d := prgb(px);
    for x := 0 to dw1 do
    begin
      fx := parx1^ - ary1;
      if (fx >= 0) and (fx < bmp.width )then
      begin
        fy := parx2^ + ary2;
        if (fy >= 0) and (fy < bmp.height) then
        begin
          prgb_s := srcrows[fy];
          inc(prgb_s, fx);
          prgb_d^ := prgb_s^;
        end;
      end;
      inc(prgb_d);
      inc(parx1);
      inc(parx2);
    end;


  end;

  freemem(srcrows);
  freemem(arx1);
  freemem(arx2);

  bmp.Assign( dst );
  FreeAndNil(dst);

end;

end.
```

Comment: The routine provided is for VCL while the original code is for Firemonkey, where the problem of rotation is natively solved including transparency. Thanks in any case, for your contribution.